# Example of mapping which maps upper half plane onto unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the mapping $w(z)$ which maps upper half plane $\Im z>0$ onto unit circle $|w|<1$ such that

$w(i)=0$ and $\arg w'(i)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

In general I can the find the mapping which satisfies above condition. But what does mean $\arg w'(i)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$?

I would be very grateful if anyone can explain the meaning of this condition in concrete example?

Answer (score 2):

The number $w'(i)$ is a complex number. The idea is to choose $w$ so that$$w'(i)=r\left(\cos\left(-\frac\pi2\right)+\sin\left(-\frac\pi2\right)i\right)\left(=-ri\right),$$for some $r\in(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer! I guess that I got you! +1